# Can I use Ubuntu 8.10 on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: boot, linux, ubuntu, compatibility, software-compatibility

I am working on a project that requires:

1. An open WiFi network
2. On that network, a device that has a known exploit.

My plan is to use a Raspberry Pi to create that open WiFi network, then use another Raspberry Pi as the exploitable device. I know there may be CPU architecture issues.

Since [Ubuntu 8.10](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/8.10/) has a [known exploit](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/8572), I want to know:

1) Is it possible to use Ubuntu 8.10 on a Raspberry Pi?

1.1) If so, would I need to use the x86 image, AMD64 image, MID USB image, or another one?

1.2) If so, are there specific models of Raspberry Pi that would or would not work with Ubuntu 8.10? I own 4Bs, a 3B+, and multiple Zero Ws. I could possibly get others as well if need be.

2) What kind of software would I need to make installation media with Ubuntu 8.10 for a Raspberry Pi?

If this turns out to not be feasible, you can expect a question along the lines of "What OS can I use on a Raspberry Pi that has a known exploit?".

Thanks for all y'all's help.

Comment: You need to ask Ubuntu.  I doubt there is any Ubuntu build older than a year or so which could work on the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you won't be able to run a 2.6 kernel on a Pi without a major rewrite, which could even accidentally fix the vulnerability you're after.

If it doesn't have to be a kernel vulnerability, my advice is to pick one in application software, e.g. Apache or PHP. It's much easier to build an old application SW from sources, compared to the kernel.

PS. I remember there was a [discussion](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/122030/33476) about a bug in `sudo`, which should still be present in Raspbian releases from 2020 and older. That's not a network-related bug though.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your requirements and after all that I want to suggest you **Lubuntu** [just a lightweight ubuntu flavour] [this](https://lubuntu.me/) is its official website, also its mentioned on Ubuntu's official website.

[image: This screenshot will be helpful for you.]

Comment: Lubuntu does not have a known exploit/vulnerability, which is the most important requirement for this part of my project.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.